# Angular parent to child binding change detection

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-template

In a nutshell, I have a component which works as a text input. The parent component passes data into this component using `@Input` bindings. When the change event gets fired via the `@Output` binding, I perform some automatic validation in the parent component. This is to remove erroneous values and replace them with some sensible default for a better user experience.

Here is a basic version of the parent component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `
    <div>
        <child [value]="item.key1"
               (valueChange)="onValueChange($event)">
            </child>
    </div>
    `
})
export class Parent {
    item = {
        key1: 'test value',
        key2: 'another test value'
    };

    onValueChange(newValue) {
        // Perform some validation and set default
        if (newValue.length > 4) {
            newValue = newValue.substring(0, 4);
        }

        this.item.key1 = newValue;
    }
}
```

And the child component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: `
    <div>
        <input type="text"
               [(ngModel)]="value"
               (blur)="onBlur($event)" />
    </div>
    `
})
export class Child {
    @Input() value: string;
    @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();

    onBlur() {
        this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
    }
}
```

See [here for a Plunker example](https://embed.plnkr.co/BjpnXbj3suvtrI6Q/)

The issue I am having is as follows:

When entering a value in the child input and firing the `blur` event, the new value is bubbled up to the parent and the validation is applied - if the validation causes the value to get modified, it bubbles back down to the child's value correctly - happy days.

However, if the first 4 characters stay the same, and you append additional characters, upon `blur` the validation will still be applied and the parent's value will get updated correctly, but the child will preserve the "invalid" value - no more happy days.

So it looks to me like Angular isn't detecting the change in the parents data (fair enough because it hasn't technically changed) so it isn't sending the "latest" value back down to the child.

My question is, how can I get the child text input to always show the correct value from the parent, even if it technically hasn't "changed"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**better solution**

@Jota.Toledo's good comment made me realise that my approach, although it did serve as a quick workaround for me at the time, it's not a good one, so I actually went and made some changes to my project that can work for you as well, also following his suggestion of

> Delegating that "validation" logic into the child component

while keeping the validation definition in the parent as a function that's passed to the child as an `@Input` param.

This way I'd give the parent 2 public vars

- a object (item)
- a function (validation)

and change `onValueChange` function to only update the item.key1 as it will be already validated.

In the child add a new `@Input` param (validation) of type `Function` and use that function to validate the newValue inside the onBlur, before emiting the value to the parent.

I have the feeling that what I've written here might "sound" a bit confusing so I'm adding the code for what I'm trying to explain.

Parent

```
@Component({
selector: 'parent',
template: `
<div>
    <p><b>This is the parent component</b></p>
    <child [value]="item.key1"
           [validation]="validation"
           (valueChange)="onValueChange($event)">
        </child>
    <p><b>Variable Value:</b> {{item | json}} </p>
</div>
`
})
   export class Parent {
   item = {
       key1: 'test value',
       key2: 'another test value'
   };

   validation = (newValue) => {
       if (newValue.length > 4) {
           newValue = newValue.substring(0, 4);
       }

       return newValue;
   }

   onValueChange(newValue) {
       this.item.key1 = newValue;
   }
}
```

Child (leaving the template part out because it's unchanged)

```
export class Child {
    @Input() value: string;
    @Input() validation: Function;
    @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();

    onBlur() {
        this.value = this.validation(this.value)
        this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
    }
}
```

**previous answer (not a good approach)**

I had a similar problem in the past and the way I solved was to clear my var and then giving it the final value inside a `setTimeout` without specifying the milliseconds.

in your parent component it would look something like this:

```
onValueChange(newValue) {
    console.log('Initial: ' + newValue);

    if (newValue.length > 4) {
        newValue = newValue.substring(0, 4);
    }
    console.log('Final: ' + newValue);
    this.item.key1 = '';
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.item.key1 = newValue;
    });

}
```

Comment: Although this solves the problem, it lacks an explanation as to why it works.  **Personally**,  I strongly discourage the use of `setTimeout` as a workaround, as it depends on an implementation detail of the framework which is the fact that `setTimeout` triggers a change detection cycle. Furthermore, it couples the application to the `window.setTimeout` function, which may not be available in other platforms (SSR). In most cases, the use of it can be avoided by using a different approach to the issue.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo you're absolutely right, I've updated my own project and also my answer to this, based on your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> However, if the first 4 characters stay the same, and you append
>   additional characters, upon blur the validation will still be applied
>   and the parent's value will get updated correctly, but the child will
>   preserve the "invalid" value - no more happy days.
>
> So it looks to me like Angular isn't detecting the change in the
>   parents data (fair enough because it hasn't technically changed) so it
>   isn't sending the "latest" value back down to the child.

Correct. The fact is that angular is "caching" the latest value passed through the `value` input property, and as you recognize, you arent really pushing new values into it if you dont change the first 4 chars.

You can check this by adding `ngOnChanges(changes)` to your child and logging the *changes* value into console; in the above case nothing is logged, as no new value for `value` is pushed through.

You could overcome this by:

- Enforcing that a new value is always pushed through the input property by *wrapping* the value in an object and *unwrapping* it in the child component. (Bad approach IMO)
- *Delegating* that "validation" logic into the child component, so that only "validated" values are emitted through the output property.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I was seeing and providing some suggestions on the ways I can overcome this, it really helped

Answer (score -1):

You should create a `Subject` on the `ParentComponent` :

```
export class ParentComponent {
  parentSubject:Subject<Item> = new Subject();

  notifyChildren() {
    this.parentSubject.next('new item value');
  }
 }
```

Pass it as `Input()` on the `ChildComponent` :

```
<child [parentSubject]="parentSubject"></child>
```

And finally `subscribe` to it on the `ChildComponent` :

```
export class ChildComponent {
@Input() parentSubject:Subject<Item>;

ngOnInit() {
 this.parentSubject.subscribe(event => {
   //do your stuff with the updated value
 });
}
```

Comment: Angular already has it's own way to notify about changes. So there is no reason to duplicate this functionality using reactive.

Answer (score -1):

you can update your code for onValueChange method in parent.ts with following

```
onValueChange(newValue) {
        this.item.key1 = null;
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Initial: ' + newValue);

            if (newValue.length > 4) {
                newValue = newValue.substring(0, 4);
            }
            console.log('Final: ' + newValue);

            this.item.key1 = newValue;
        })
    }
```

Comment: Although this solves the problem, it lacks an explanation as to why it works. Personally, I strongly discourage the use of setTimeout as a workaround, as it depends on an implementation detail of the framework which is the fact that setTimeout triggers a change detection cycle. Furthermore, it couples the application to the window.setTimeout function, which may not be available in other platforms (SSR). In most cases, the use of it can be avoided by using a different approach to the issue.